# Set equalizer settings that works for all sounds from any programs?

Tags: music-player

Can we set equalizer sound settings in some program, then go to any other program that produces sound knowing that those settings would apply?  For example, set it so that bass is enhanced across the board.

Answer (score 2):

**[DSP Manager](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/features/dsp-equalizer)** (root only) is an app that's incorporated into a number of custom ROMs.  I have it in my [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) but I know it's available in others or as a stand alone (that you have to flash over your current ROM) depending on your device.  Search XDA for "DSP Manager" in relation to your specific device as there are numerous device specific threads and downloads.

Comment: So if i want to add my own equalizer to the app that support all the devices then that all  devices should be root only right ?

Answer (score 0):

Not without a custom kernel, AFAIK.  Equalisation across the board is controlled by the kernel and I don't believe the settings are accessible to apps.  So an app needs its own equaliser to apply to the sound before it's played.

If you're using a Galaxy S, one such custom kernel is called Voodoo Sound.

**Edit:** [The paid version of Voodoo Sound](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.controlappdonate) now only requires root, rather than a custom kernel.

Comment: So to make Equalizer in My app, It must that my device has been rooted. right ?